# Disable autosuggestion tags in admin area Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, autosuggest

I have about 50M tags for Posts. Its annoying to work with Post when add tags autocomplete can freeze browser. Is any native function to disable autosuggestion tags?
I try this way but it disable tags functionality at all:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'disable_auto_tag_suggestion' );
function disable_auto_tag_suggestion() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'suggest' );
}
```